# css select every 2nd element in mixed list

Tags: css

There are a lot of questions of this nature but I cannot find a solution to the following:

```
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="noRow"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="noRow"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="noRow"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="noRow"></div>
...
```

I would like to change the background colour of every second `.row`

I've tried:

```
.row:nth-child(odd)
```

Nothing changes

```
.row:nth-child(even)
```

Changes the background colour for all `.row` elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.row:nth-child(4n - 1)` or `.row:not(:nth-child(4n + 1))`.

```css
.row:nth-child(4n - 1) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">Row</div>
<div class="noRow">noRow</div>
<div class="row">Row</div>
<div class="noRow">noRow</div>
<div class="row">Row</div>
<div class="noRow">noRow</div>
<div class="row">Row</div>
<div class="noRow">noRow</div>
<div class="row">Row</div>
<div class="noRow">noRow</div>
<div class="row">Row</div>
<div class="noRow">noRow</div>
<div class="row">Row</div>
<div class="noRow">noRow</div>
<div class="row">Row</div>
<div class="noRow">noRow</div>
```

Comment: Isn't quite correct. Take a look here [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexChariz/g9rcpesa/)

Comment: @AlexChar - It's because you are using `div:nth-child(4n - 1)`.

Comment: Yes i know. Is the same in your example if use `div:nth-child(4n - 1)` instead. My point is doesn't depend on the class of the element.

Comment: @AlexChar - Found a solution. -------> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/g9rcpesa/1/)